# find command sometimes results in non-matching files being zipped

Tags: find, directory, timestamps

I'm trying to make a zip file of all the files in a specific directory which were modified in the last x minutes.

Here's my command:

```
find "/path/to/dir" -mmin -30 -not -name ".*" -exec zip -r "testfile.zip" "{}" \+
```

If I make the modify time small enough, then it correctly identifies the one file that I recently changed.

The problem is... if I increase the minimum modify time to, say, 50 (it keeps changing), then the zip file adds **all** of the files in /path/to/dir. Even though all the files were **definitely** not changed.

So somehow, there is a specific file that is causing the whole find command to blow up. I looked through all the recently modified files (within last day) for a file with spaces in it or something, but I didn't find any. And it shouldn't matter, since I'm quoting the braces, right?

What else could be causing this weird behavior?

Comment: Was the directory recently modified? Try putting `-not -type d` in there so that `find` won't match the directory itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `find` includes everything in its search: directories, files, and symlinks.

```
find "/path/to/dir" -mmin -30 -not -name ".*" -exec zip -r "testfile.zip" "{}" \+
```

If `/path/to/dir` was modified in the last 30 minutes, it will pass all the tests, and `zip`, since it was given the `-r` option, will add the directory and everything under it to the archive.

You can approach this in a few ways, using either (or both) of the following:

- Don't give `zip` the `-r` option. You're only interested in recently-modified files rather than every file that is in a recently-modified directory.
- Add the `-not -type d` test to the `find` expression, so that it doesn't match directories.

```
find "/path/to/dir" -not -type d -mmin -30 -not -name ".*" -exec zip "testfile.zip" "{}" \+
```

Comment: Thanks again - leaving out the '-r' turned out to be the better option. I didn't realize that the files would still retain their parent folder structure with that option turned off.